# How to use css to keep horizontal visible when vertical is auto?

Tags: css, html, overflow

There are three div, d1, d2 and d3, I want the d1 can wrap the content for vertical, but visible for horizontal.

If d2 and d3 have no float properity, d1 will give me the result I want.

but d2 and d2 have float properity, I need add overflow-y:auto to make it wrap vertical.

and I added overflow-x:visible, but it still have a scroll bar.

so how to keep the horizontal visible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
#d1
{
    background-color:red;
    padding:10px;
    width:100px;

    overflow-x:visible;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
#d2
{
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;

    width:150px;
    height:30px;
}
#d3
{
    background-color:green;
    float:left;

    width:50px;
    height:230px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="d1">
    <div id="d2">in</div>
    <div id="d3">
        out
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question, you can solve this using a "clear" DIV. Edited code:

**CSS**

```
<style>
#d1
{
    background-color:red;
    padding:10px;
    width:100px;

    overflow-x:visible;

}
#d2
{
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;

    width:150px;
    height:30px;
}
#d3
{
    background-color:green;
    float:left;

    width:50px;
    height:230px;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="d2">in</div>
    <div id="d3">out</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```